# Can't load local json on phonegap app on android

Tags: android, json, cordova, ampersand.js

I have a problem with the offline mode of my app on android (an Ampersandjs app).
When offline mode is activate, all of the data has been stored in the cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ folder and instead of making call to an external PHP REST API the app store json files locally.

On IOS it's ok but Android doesn't want load the files when the app is starting and the google Network dev tools indicate the files status is 'pending'.

However if i stored this files on an external server it's ok.

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using (cordova --version will tell you).  If you are at Version 5 or higher you may need to look at your Content Security Policy although I would have expected iOS to also not work if that was the issue, may be worth investigating though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Phonegap version cli-5.x, you need to use whitelist plugin. Try adding following lines in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for whitelist plugin description

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, but my config.xml seem be ok, it's strange i don't know if the problem comes from framework (Ampersandjs) or android environment or config.xml, on ios : ok and android nok :[

Comment: I have also faced same issue during our app migration from Phonegap v3.6 to Cli-5.2.0. It was working fine on iOS but on Android it was throwing 404 error. Once we added whitelist plugin, problem got fixed.